# Snowpark UDF with Row input type

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I would like to define a Snowpark UDF with input type [snowflake.snowpark.Row](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Row).
The reason for this is that I would like to mimic the `pandas.apply` approach
where I can define my business logic in some class, and then apply the logic to each row of the Snowpark dataframe. Each column can be easily mapped to a class attribute with [asDict](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Row.asDict)

For example (running from the Snowflake Python worksheet):

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf
from snowflake.snowpark import Row
from snowflake.snowpark.types import IntegerType


from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyEvent:
    attribute1: str = 'dummy'
    attribute2: str = 'unknown'
    def someCalculation(self) -> int:
        return len(self.attribute1) + len(self.attribute2.strip())

def testSomeCalculation():
    inputDict = {'attribute1': 'foo',
                 'attribute2': 'baz'}
    event = MyEvent(**inputDict)
    print(event.someCalculation())


def main(session: snowpark.Session):

    some_logic = udf(lambda row: MyEvent(**(row.asDict())).someCalculation()
              , return_type=IntegerType()
              , input_types=[Row])
```

However, when I try to use snowpark.Row as input type, I get an `unsupported data type`:

```
File "snowflake/snowpark/_internal/udf_utils.py", line 972, in create_python_udf_or_sp
    input_sql_types = [convert_sp_to_sf_type(arg.datatype) for arg in input_args]
  File "snowflake/snowpark/_internal/udf_utils.py", line 972, in <listcomp>
    input_sql_types = [convert_sp_to_sf_type(arg.datatype) for arg in input_args]
  File "snowflake/snowpark/_internal/type_utils.py", line 195, in convert_sp_to_sf_type
    raise TypeError(f"Unsupported data type: {datatype.__class__.__name__}")
TypeError: Unsupported data type: type
```

I see that all the UDF examples use basic types from `snowpark.types`.
Is there any fundamental reason why the input type cannot be a snowpark.Row ?

I know I could list explicitly all `MyEvent` attributes in `input_type=[]`,
but that is going to be error prone and defeating the purpose of designing
my code around a class representing my business object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution tested in Snowflake Python worksheet, based on the suggestion by @felipe-hoffa above

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, udf
from snowflake.snowpark.types import IntegerType, VariantType
    
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    
    @dataclass
    class MyEvent:
        attribute1: str = 'dummy'
        attribute2: str = 'unknown'
        def someText(self) -> str:
            return f"someText {len(self.attribute1)} : {self.attribute1=}, {self.attribute2=}"

    def wrap_some_text(x) -> str:
        return MyEvent(**json.loads(x)).someText()
    
    my_event_get_text = udf(lambda x: wrap_some_text(x), return_type=VariantType(), input_types=[VariantType()])

    df = session.create_dataframe(['{"attribute1":"value1", "attribute2":"value20"}']).to_df("col1")
    df = df.select(col("col1"),
                   my_event_get_text(col("col1").astype("variant")).as_("my_event_get_text")
                  ).show()
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the official type mapping for Python UDFs in Snowflake:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf-stored-procedure-data-type-mapping#label-sql-python-data-type-mappings

If you want to receive a `dict`, then make the input a `dict` (which in SQL will be a `variant` or `object`).

Then instead of processing the row, just transform the row to dict before sending it to the UDF.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, you did put me on the right track.
I managed to get it to work with a small modification, namely a `json.loads` to convert the variant to a dict. Posting the complete solution in a separate answer because it won't fit the character limit here.